# Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in ubuntu

Tags: ldap, apache-2.4, php5

I'm attempting to set up a test ldap server on an ubuntu 12 VM. I've gotten this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in ubuntu
```

I've installed the gettext extension in phpbrew to my 5.4.34 in use.

Running aptitude show php5-ldap in the ubuntu VM I get this response:

```
Package: php5-ldap                
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Version: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9
Priority: optional
Section: php
```

Here are the contents of the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

```
ldap.conf
ldap.load
... more
```

And I've restarted the apache server, even rebooted the VM.

The admin page shows this:

```
Your install of PHP appears to be missing LDAP support.

Please install LDAP support before using phpLDAPadmin.
(Dont forget to restart your web server afterwards)
info    Configuration setting already defined.
A call has been made to reset a configuration value (server,host,newdom.biz)
info    Configuration setting already defined.
A call has been made to reset a configuration value (login,bind_id,cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com)
```

I went through grief trying to figure out the config file. Given that my hosts file is set to respond to newdom.biz.

```
$servers->newServer('ldap_pla');
$servers->setValue('server','host','ldap://ldap.newdom.biz');
$servers->setValue('server','host','newdom.biz');
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=newdom,dc=biz'));
```

`php -m | grep ldap` yields empty so clearly php, or at least phpbrew doesn't know about it. I've googled for it and could use phpbrew to point to that library, but after installing slapd ldap-utils I'm unsure where the library is. Perhaps it won't get mixed up with the module in apache?

Perhaps this is where my goof is? I'm sure I made a goof somewhere but am not seeing it now, thx, sam

Comment: Does `php -m | grep ldap` output a result ?

Comment: Good call. It opens up a vector and asked in my question.

Comment: I rewrote my answer according to your answer to my question

Comment: What is the output for `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep ldap`

Comment: Yes, it's there: dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldas, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp     And util_ldap shows up in modules.

Comment: Seems you have something weird in your config. What's your Linux flavour ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's me. lab_release returns: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: For some reason phpbrew wouldn't install the ldap extension. I've installed it via apt-get. The command to use to point to the /lib directory: phpbrew ext install ldap -- --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu